# columna «id» fue especificada más de una vez

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

Estoy desarrollando en PostGIS el siguiente código el cual contiene un mismo nombre de columna llamado "id" en las tablas sigpac_2005_ca, sigpac_2005_co y sigpac_2005_gr. De modo que no sé cómo puedo juntar mis 4 tablas usando la herramienta INNER JOIN incluyendo el campo "id".

ERROR:  la columna «id» fue especificada más de una vez.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_table1 AS
SELECT *
FROM pac_2005_corregido
INNER JOIN sigpac_2005_ca
ON pac_2005_corregido."cod_prov" = sigpac_2005_ca."prov" 
AND pac_2005_corregido."cod_mun" = sigpac_2005_ca."mun"
INNER JOIN sigpac_2005_co
ON pac_2005_corregido."cod_prov" = sigpac_2005_co."prov" 
AND pac_2005_corregido."cod_mun" = sigpac_2005_co."mun"
INNER JOIN sigpac_2005_gr
ON pac_2005_corregido."cod_prov" = sigpac_2005_gr."prov" 
AND pac_2005_corregido."cod_mun" = sigpac_2005_gr."mun"
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un alias así

```
SELECT column_name AS alias_name
FROM table_name;
```

cambiando el nombre repetido por lo que te parezca mejor, con eso debería de solucionarse

[documentación](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-column-alias/)

Answer (score 0):

Debes especificar campos diferentes si vas a crear una tabla, así que evita el asterisco al hacer joins.

Especifica todos los campos que deseas para la selección:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_table1 AS
SELECT pac_2005_corregido.id AS id_pac2005_corregido
       , sigpac_2005_co.id AS id_sigpac_co
       , sigpac_2005_gr.id AS id_sigpac_2005_gr
       , _resto_de_campos_
FROM pac_2005_corregido
INNER JOIN sigpac_2005_ca
ON pac_2005_corregido."cod_prov" = sigpac_2005_ca."prov" 
AND pac_2005_corregido."cod_mun" = sigpac_2005_ca."mun"
INNER JOIN sigpac_2005_co
ON pac_2005_corregido."cod_prov" = sigpac_2005_co."prov" 
AND pac_2005_corregido."cod_mun" = sigpac_2005_co."mun"
INNER JOIN sigpac_2005_gr
ON pac_2005_corregido."cod_prov" = sigpac_2005_gr."prov" 
AND pac_2005_corregido."cod_mun" = sigpac_2005_gr."mun"
```